i have two patch antenna (coaxial ) and i want to put csrr
i have two patch antenna (coaxial ) and i want to put csrr and i dont get any result on Hfss i substract the Csrr from the ground and from the substract and still same result with and without


(substract I know subtract and substrate.)

I see what might be the center conductor of coax but I don't see where the shield is connected.
I also don't know what Csrr is, the significance of subraction in this context, and I don't fully understand the geometry from the 2D drawing.

could you please provide me your email to send you all info you need, im tired with this problem
